# TripAdvisor Web Scraping a specific value is not possible

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I'm new to web scraping and want to get a specific value from a few specific TripAdvisor sites like [this](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187399-d200757-Reviews-Pullman_Dresden_Newa_Hotel-Dresden_Saxony.html)  I need the value for cleanliness which is 4,5 in this example. No matter what part of the HTML I try, it's not able to get it. On sites like booking or holidaycheck it works like a charm.

[image: Value needed is 4,5]

````
import requests
from lxml import html
import time

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g187399-d200757-Reviews-Pullman_Dresden_Newa_Hotel-Dresden_Saxony.html'

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

time.sleep(5)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)


```cleanliness_xpath = "//div[@class='uqMDf z BGJxv YGfmd YQkjl']//div[@class='ZPHZV']//div[@class='tJRnI']/span[contains(text(), 'Cleanliness')]/following-sibling::div[@class='BqYzr']/span[@class='MUlry']"  

cleanliness_element = tree.xpath(cleanliness_xpath)

# Überprüfen, ob ein Wert gefunden wurde
if cleanliness_element:
    cleanliness_rating = float(cleanliness_element[0].text) / 10  
    print(f"Cleanliness rating: {cleanliness_rating}")
else:
    print("Cleanliness rating not found")
````

Answer (score 0):

To get the cleanliness value you need to change the cleanliness_xpath value.

```
cleanliness_xpath = "//div[contains(@data-tab, 'TABS_ABOUT')]//span[contains(., 'Cleanliness')]/following-sibling::span"
```

For me the above xpath worked fine.

Explanation:

```
//div[contains(@data-tab, 'TABS_ABOUT')] - This will go to the About section in the web page
//span[contains(., 'Cleanliness')] - This will go to the Cleanliness rating line
```

HTML code block of Cleanliness rating line

```
<div class="tJRnI">
        <span>Cleanliness</span>
        <div class="BqYzr">
                <div class="WXMiS" style="width:89.457368px"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="MUlry">4.5</span>
</div>
```

As per the above html code, after Cleanliness we can find the rating

```
/following-sibling::span - This will find the span tag which is under the current parent and in the same level with the current tag
//div[contains(@data-tab, 'TABS_ABOUT')]//span[contains(., 'Cleanliness')]/following-sibling::span - This will go to the About section, then to the span tag which contains Cleanliness string and checks for the span tag which is in the same level as current.
```

Below is the output i got.
It's not 4.5 as you are dividing the rating by 10.

Cleanliness rating: 0.45